# How to convert ArrayList<Uri> to string?

Tags: android, string, sqlite, uri

I store my uri's in `ArrayList<Uri> imageUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();`

How can I convert them to string? I'm Planning to store them in sqlite database.

**update:**

```
ListView listView;
ArrayList<Uri> imageUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
ArrayAdapter<Uri> arrayAdapter;

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Uri>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, imageUri);
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

if (!imageUri.isEmpty()) {

        Uri uri0 = imageUri.get(0);
        String uri_0 = uri0.toString();
}
```

Is it right doing it this way? Storing the uri_0 in sqlite database. This way I'll get each uri per index?

Comment: Loop over the list and create a new list with every URI's string representation. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I think it should be `List<URI>`

Comment: @JeroenVannevel i've updated my question and posted some codes..

Comment: After update: It would be the correct way just for the first item. If you place that within a loop, you'll get all and correct will be ok.

Comment: @Jane I just posted an answer on how to iterate through the whole ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and cleanest way (since j8) is probably using lambdas:

`List<String> targetList = new ArrayList<String>();
imageUri.forEach(uri -> targetList.add(uri.toString()));`

Answer (score 0):

I'd just call the `toString()` method over your URI object which would return the URI's string representation. Afterwards you should only need to loop over your `ArrayList` and call that method and do whatever you need with the returned value.

Comment: The `Uri` class already has `toString()` which provides a string representation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html